# Dairy suddenly has an odd taste

Tags: flavor

Over the past year, more and more brands of dairy product — and some other products containing milk as an ingredient — have suddenly begun tasting odd to me. I can't quite describe the flavor; it's unlike anything I have tasted before. It's vaguely "green," not chemical-y, but quite gross and ruins the flavor of many things that used to be delicious. The things most affected are sour cream, yogurt, cottage cheese; mozzarella, Monterey jack, cream and Neufchatel cheeses and, oddly, ranch dressing. Milk, cream, hard and aged cheeses taste totally normal. Not all brands have this odd taste, but the list is growing.

I first noticed it in the Walmart store brand products about 8 or 9 months ago. Hiland, Daisy, Philadephia, Yoplait, Chobani, etc. were unaffected. I thought the cheap brands must be adding some new ingredient, but there's nothing new. In the past 2 or 3 months, Hiland cottage cheese and Philadelphia cream cheese have also begun to have this odd, unpalatable taste, as has Daisy sour cream. What on earth is going on?

And before anyone puts it down to just my taste changing — I reiterate that not all brands have this strange taste, even though the ingredients may be the same. And it's not something that's changed with the milk itself, I don't think, because milk, half-and-half, and whipping cream don't taste this way, nor do cheddar, Swiss, parmesan, etc. Whatever is going on, it tastes revolting.

Any ideas?

Comment: From the Walmast mention I assume you are in the US?

Comment: During the past 5 years, I've noticed a slow transition of dairy products causing kidney, bladder and prostate issues. Urinating 6 times a day is normal. Do take notice of whether your urination increases to 11 or 12 times in a day or there is double voiding or a lower flow rate or bladder pains or slight leaking of urine after urinating. If it does, stop dairy and meat consumption and you should recover in 2 weeks. As of now I can only suspect that some problem with dairy might be the cause of a spike in some cancers.

Answer (score 4):

The flavor of milk actually *does* change through the year.

I suspect that it’s more significant in some breeds of cows than others, or maybe it’s just that some cows are fed so much grain through the year that it’s not noticeable.

In major cheese producing areas (like the Netherlands), they make a distinction between summer and winter cheeses, as one is made from grass fed cows while the other from hay (hooikaas, hay cheese).  [Graskaas](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graskaas) (grass cheese) is specifically the cheese made from the first milkings after the cows have started back on fresh grass.

Comment: Right. I know what the animal eats affects the milk (hello, goats grazing wild garlic, lol). This is different. And milk and cream never, ever have the weird flavor. Only milk products. It's very odd.

Comment: @lemonpiewriter there’s also been a crackdown on kids being used to clean factory equipment.  If their hands could get into smaller places to do a more thorough cleaning, maybe you’re sensitive to the cleaning products residue?  That might explain why it’s only milk derived products and not milk itself

Comment: Now that is definitely a possibility, and something that hadn't occurred to me.